# Change the values of select

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drop-down-menu

Hi guys I have 2 dropdown list and I need when I click in any option of the dropdown 1 change the options of a dropdown 2 for example:

Dropdown menu 1    Dropdown menu 2
  - Option 1
  - Option 2
  - Option 3

If I select in the dropdown 1 ("Option 1") automatic the dropdown 2 will update with some values, if I select in the dropdown 2 ("Option 2") the dropdown 2 will update with some values and the same for other options!!!

How I can do that using Javascript or Jquery?

Comment: Bind change event for dropdown menu 1 and in that event update the values of dropdown menu 2. That's the approach. Now share your code so that we can help you with it :)

Comment: Yessss theinvisible that's exactly what I need! Thank you so much my friend! Good Bless you... Here the link for peoples that have the same problem!  http://javascript.about.com/library/bldydrop1.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming id's of one and two on your dropdowns, you could do something like this in your javascript code:

```
(function(){
  $(function () {
    $("#one").change(function(){
      //if you want to load them from somewhere
      //$("#two").load({url});

      //if you want to manually load them
      $("#two option").remove();
      if($(this).val() == 1)
        $("#two").append("<option value='11'>eleven</option>");
      else if($(this).val() == 2)
        $("#two").append("<option value='22'>twenty-two</option>");
    });
  })
} ());
```

when the first drop-down changes, the values in the second will as well. if you want to load the new options from the server, use the commented jQuery 'load' function with your URL. if you know the items you want, you can just add them manually as the code above does.

Example:  http://plnkr.co/edit/yE0m4ZwwE1P6LT0VGuYE?p=info

Comment: Hey guys I made this: http://plnkr.co/edit/StxDCVTFsjLieObJhQlE?p=preview     and it work! but I want to add more than 1 option

Comment: Then repeat the 3 javascript lines [starting with var option = document.createElement("option")] for however many options you need to add.

Answer (score 0):

You can go for simple javascript dropdown on change event. You can also take out the **first dropdown text as well as value.** by calling a javascript function and taking out value by id of the first dropdown. And can assign to new dropdown. Please refer the attached sample code

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function doChange() 
{
    var dropDown1 = document.getElementById("mydropdown");
    var dropDown2 = document.getElementById("mydropdown2");


    var op = new Option();
    op.value = dropDown1.options[dropDown1.selectedIndex].value;
    op.text = dropDown1.options[dropDown1.selectedIndex].text ;
    document.getElementById("mydropdown2").options.length = 0;  
    dropDown2.options.add(op);

}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form>
<select name="mydropdown" id="mydropdown" onchange="doChange()">
<option value="dummy1">display1</option>
<option value="dummy2">display2</option>
<option value="dummy3">display3</option>
</select>
<br/>

<select name="mydropdown2" id="mydropdown2">
</select>
</form>
</body>
```